# The rebooting proccess stuck on a certain unknown image

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed successfully Ubuntu Gnome on my MBP 2012 in dual-booting. When I restart my computer, the proccess of rebooting stuck on the following page. How could I force the proccess to access my OS?

[image]